# Plugion: Display Posts Shortcode - how remove strong tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/ to display listings of posts in a page.

```
[display-posts id="48, 46" include_excerpt="true"]
```

It outputs

```
<ul class="display-posts-listing">
    <li class="listing-item">
        <strong><a href="" class="title">title</a><span class="excerpt">text<br><br><a href="" class="more-link">Read More</a></span></strong>
    </li>
    <li class="listing-item">
        <strong><a href="" class="title">title</a><span class="excerpt">text<br><br><a href="" class="more-link">Read More</a></span></strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I do not understand why it adds strong tag. How can I remove it. When I echo the output value of be_display_posts_shortcode function, the strong tag is not exists.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.display-posts-listing li a').unwrap('<strong></strong>');
});
```

Comment: Do not want to use Jquery for that. Need to know how it is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It's the shortcode in the editor.

If the shortcode is inserted (alone) in the visual area, it is automatically wrapped with  - tags. You can remove them in the text view.

I hope this helps others with this problem, also with other shortcodes!